# git: Make a clean history after merging multiple times from a feature branch that is subsequently rebased

Tags: git, rebase

Suppose I am working on some feature in a branch B. My feature depends on another feature that my colleague works on in a branch A.

I work closely with my colleague, so during development he will often update A with new stuff that I need in B. The way I get his changes in is to just merge with his branch. So what I do in B is something like the following:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b B
..
git commit Some work
..
git commit More work
..
git fetch origin
git merge origin/A
..
git commit Event more work
..
git fetch origin
git merge origin/A
..
git commit And even more work
..
git fetch origin
git merge origin/A
...
```

This works very well. The problem is that we want to get this into master and to have a nice clean history. In particular we want to:

1. Clean up the history of A using some kind of rebase
2. Clean up the history of B using some kind of rebase
3. Commit first A and then B to master without all the extra merges above.

The only way I can come up with to do this is to:

1. Rebase A into master in the usual way
2. Cherry pick all the non-merge commits from B onto master.

One problem with this is that I manually have to cherry pick the non-merge commits.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Well instead of manually cherry-picking, you can automatically cherry-pick, i.e. rebase:

```
git rebase A B
```

git will automatically:

- find out the parent commit between A and B
- go over all commits in B to be applied on top of A
- figure out that some commits are already in `A` and do not need to be applied again.

However, you potentially might run into a lot of conflicts along the way.

I suggest that, if a clean history at the moment of merging is import to you, you adjust your workflow to have `git rebase origin/A` instead of `git merge origin/A`, which means your history will remain clean. You may also want to read up on git rebase workflows a little.

Answer (score 0):

A common technique used in numpy development is to squash the feature branch into a single commit. This is probably not as effective as [@Cimbali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54272828/2988730) for a smaller project, but it works really well for something the size of numpy, where the granularity of a single PR is very small with respect to the entire project. One advantage of doing the cleanup with a rebase is that you can move everything into a guaranteed fast-forwardable state well before doing any merging.

A standard command would be something like

```
git rebase -i master
```

Then select `fixup` for all commits except the first and let it roll.

Comment: Interactive rebase with the intertwined branch `A` / branch `B` history will be messy, but luckily the end result can be achieved directly with `git merge --squash`